# GUI glitch using paste?

Tags: awk, paste

this is my file:

file.txt

```
cg13869341      1       15865
cg24669183      1       534242
cg15560884      1       710097
cg01014490      1       714177
cg17505339      1       720865
cg11954957      1       758829
cg23803172      1       763119
cg16736630      1       779995
cg00168193      1       790667
cg05898754      1       805102
```

`awk '{print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $3 "\t" $1}' file.txt`

output

```
 1       cg13869341
 1       cg24669183
 1       cg15560884
 1       cg01014490
 1       cg17505339
 1       cg11954957
 1       cg23803172
 1       cg16736630
 1       cg00168193
 1       cg05898754
```

`awk '{print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $3 "\t" $1}' file.txt | head -1 | tr '\t' '\n'`

output

```
 1
 15865
 15865
 cg13869341
```

Ok, the format is inherently correct, but the output is strange. So I try something else.

`awk '{print $1}' file.txt > 1.txt
awk '{print $2}' file.txt > 2.txt
awk '{print $3}' file.txt > 3.txt`

`paste 2.txt 3.txt 3.txt 1.txt | head`

```
 1       cg13869341
 1       cg24669183
 1       cg15560884
 1       cg01014490
 1       cg17505339
 1       cg11954957
 1       cg23803172
 1       cg16736630
 1       cg00168193
 1       cg05898754
```

pasting 2.txt 3.txt gives the expected output (cut to head -2):

```
 1       15865
 1       534242
```

as does 3.txt and 1.txt:

```
 15865   cg13869341
 534242  cg24669183
```

So why when I paste 2.txt 3.txt 3.txt 1.txt, the middle 2 columns disappear?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the behavior with a file that has Windows line endings (`\r\n` instead of `\n`). In this case, the last field will not be `"15865"` but `"15865\r"`, so every time `$3` is printed, the cursor is moved to the beginning of the line before the next tab and field are printed. The next field then overwrites the just written `$3`, or part of it if it is shorter.

You can convert the file to UNIX line endings with a number of tools such as `fromdos`, `dos2unix` or `recode`. A way to do it on the fly in awk is

```
awk '{ sub(/\r$/, ""); print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $3 "\t" $1 }' file
```

Style note: Instead of hard-coding the separator, consider using the `OFS` special variable:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ sub(/\r$/, ""); print $2, $3, $3, $1 }' file
```

That makes the command easier to adapt in case you want to generate differently separated values later.